Command line to convert midi into mp3 while adjusting channel level?
I have a midi file with multiple channels (say bass, tenor, alto, soprano). How to produce multiple mp3s with different volume distributions (say b=+0, t=+0, a=+0, s=+0; b=+0, t=-12dB, a=-12dB, s=-12dB; b=-12dB, t=+0, a=-12dB, s=-12dB; etc) in an automated way? Following Convert midi to mp3, I tried with timidity++, but I cannot figure out how to adjust volumes. Thanks in advance for any help!

That would be a question just about using programs, not about programming. Stack Overflow is for the latter - for the former see Super User.

Done! https://superuser.com/questions/1849868/command-line-to-convert-midi-into-mp3-while-adjusting-channel-level
